# slick slider creating last slide empty Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, slick.js

Can users please explain why they are downvote this question?

Facing a problem in a slick slider that it creating an empty slide at last below is my code that is written in Angular JS. How can I deactivate or remove that empty slide?

```
<slick dots=false infinite=true speed=300 slides-to-show=3 touch-move=false slides-to-scroll=1 init-onload=true data="city_section">
  <div  ng-repeat="city_s in city_section" >
    <img ng-if="city_s.search_city_image" src="<?php echo UPLOAD_PATH ?>city/{{city_s.search_city_image}}" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
</slick>
```

Comment: Can users please explain why they are downvote this question?

Comment: I think pepole or downvoting this question due to not more information given about your requirement i am saying this because i feel like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usage
Using bower to install it. bower install angular-slick-carousel
Add jquery, angular, slick-carousel and angular-slick-carousel to your code.

```
<script src="../bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script> 
<script src="../bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.js"></script> 
<script src="../bower_components/angular-slick-carousel/dist/angular-slick.min.js"></script>
```

Add the sortable module as a dependency to your application module: slickCarousel

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('MyApp', ['slickCarousel'])
```

This directive allows you to use the slick-carousel plugin as an angular directive. It can be specified in your HTML as either a  attribute or a  element.

```
 <slick infinite=true slides-to-show=3 slides-to-scroll=3>
    ...
    </slick>

    <slick 
        settings="slickConfig" ng-if="numberLoaded">
    </slick>
```

Attributes & Event
settings: optional Object containing any of the slick options. Consult here.

enabled should slick be enabled or not. Default to true. Example below
method optional containing slick method. discussed below in detail
event optional containing slick event

```
$scope.slickConfig = {
    enabled: true,
    autoplay: true,
    draggable: false,  
    autoplaySpeed: 3000,
    method: {},
    event: {
        beforeChange: function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
        },
        afterChange: function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
        }
    }
};
```

Enable/disable slick
Slick can be easily switched on and off by using enabled settings flag.

```
    $scope.slickConfig = {
        enabled: true,
    }
    $scope.toggleSlick = function() {
      $scope.slickConfig.enabled = !$scope.slickConfig.enabled;
    }
    <slick settings="slickConfig">
     ...
    </slick>
    <button ng-click="toggleSlick()">Toggle</button>
Method
All the functions in the plugin are exposed through a control attribute.
To utilize this architecture, and have two-way data-binding, define an empty control handle on scope:
    $scope.slickConfig = {
        method: {}
    }
```

Pass it as the value to control attribute. Now, you can call any plugin methods as shown in the example.

```
<button ng-click="slickConfig.method.slickGoTo(2)">slickGoTo(2)</button>
<button ng-click="slickConfig.method.slickPrev()">slickPrev()</button>
<button ng-click="slickConfig.method.slickNext()">slickNext()</button>
<button ng-click='slickConfig.method.slickAdd("<div>New</div>")'>slickAdd()</button>
<button ng-click='slickConfig.method.slickRemove(3)'>slickRemove(3)</button>
<button ng-click='slickConfig.method.slickPlay()'>slickPlay()</button>
<button ng-click='slickConfig.method.slickPause()'>slickPause()</button>
```

Slide data
For change slide content, you have to set ng-if to destroy and init it

controller:

```
 $scope.number = [{label: 1}, {label: 2}, {label: 3}, {label: 4}, {label: 5}, {label: 6}, {label: 7}, {label: 8}];
    $scope.numberLoaded = true;
    $scope.numberUpdate = function(){
        $scope.numberLoaded = false; // disable slick 

        //number update 

        $scope.numberLoaded = true; // enable slick 
    };
html:
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="tpl.html">
        <h3>{{ i.label }}</h3>
    </script> 

    <slick ng-if="numberLoaded">
        <div ng-repeat="i in number">
            <div class="" ng-include="'tpl.html'"></div>
        </div>
    </slick>
Global config
  config(['slickCarouselConfig', function (slickCarouselConfig) {
      slickCarouselConfig.dots = true;
      slickCarouselConfig.autoplay = false;
  }])
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-slick-carousel